# chown all files of removed user (symlinks)

Tags: macos, chmod

I migrated my OSX System from one machine to another. Everything works fine, but when I check the files under /usr/local, they now belong to a user 502, not my newly created user (which has the internal id 501).

Problem: even with sudo,

```
chown (-R) <username>:admin
```

did not work, the files remain unchanged.

How can I get rid of user 502?

Update: It seems normal files/dirs are changed, but symlinks aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have determined yourself you need to chown the files owned by user 502 to 501. You can do this with:

`find / -user 502 | xargs chown username:admin`

This will find all files and directories owned by user 501 and chown them to username:admin.

Comment: Thank you ... while this helped a lot, all symlinks (and thats many, since I am in the brew Cellar) are not changed. I will update the question.

Comment: You can update symlinks with with `chown -h username:admin filename`

Comment: The -h flag did it. My Solution: 

     for f in `find . -user 502`; do echo $f; chown -h <username>:admin $f; done

Comment: The `| xargs`-way would have worked just as well, and is probably faster ;)

Comment: It did not work right away, so I used the loop to print out some debug.